# Unreal Engine 5 can't find TStaticArray

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

My problem revolves around a data asset class describing a survivor for my game. The class contains an `FText` for both the name and description and it compiled fine. However, after I added a property for teachable perks, which every survivor has 3 of, it started causing issues.
At first, I thought I just forgot to include the necessary header, that being `"Containers/StaticArray.h"`, but even after that I still get an error telling me that *"a class, delegate, enum, or struct, with the name TStaticArray can not be found"*. I know that I have the correct header because I checked the documentation for the [TStaticArray](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/Containers/TStaticArray/) type so I'm stuck. It might be worth noting that intellisense does show the correct type, I can even navigate to the definition by holding down control and left-clicking on it in Visual Studio, but the compiler doesn't seem to find it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Here's the full code:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Engine/DataAsset.h"
#include "Containers/StaticArray.h"
#include "SurvivorData.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class KILLERGAME_API USurvivorData : public UPrimaryDataAsset
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
    
public:
    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, EditDefaultsOnly)
    FText Name;

    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, EditDefaultsOnly)
    FText Description;

    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, EditDefaultsOnly)
    TStaticArray<TObjectPtr<class UPerkData>, 3> TeachablePerks;
};
```

`UPerkData` is just another data asset describing a perk.

Tools used:

- Visual Studio 2022 17.8.3
- Unreal Engine 5.3

Comment: I am wondering if the problem is on array data type more than the data structure: did you try to change TObjectPtr<class UPerkData>to something else? I see in the engine code, it is used with shared_ptr and refcounter_ptr, but not objptr...

Comment: @MauroDorni It doesn't seem to matter what kind of template type I give it. I tried a C++ raw pointer, the `std::shared_ptr`, I even tried including the header `UPerkData` was declared in and not forward declaring it. Nothing has worked so far, it's still the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I think I've figured it out.

I had the correct header file and the template type doesn't matter. `TStaticArray` simply doesn't work as a `UPROPERTY`. Using it as a normal field works fine.

So that answers that.

No to my workaround to achieve the limiting of the array length to 3.
I had to fall back to old faithful and use a simple `TArray`. I only care about limiting its size in the editor since it is a data asset. So I added a constructor that initializes the array with 3 empty slots, added `EditFixedSize` to the metadata, and overwrote the const version of the `IsDataValid` method derived from `UObject`. In it, I simply define the object as invalid should the array size not equal 3.

Here's the code:

Header:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Engine/DataAsset.h"
#include "PerkData.h"
#include "SurvivorData.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class KILLERGAME_API USurvivorData : public UPrimaryDataAsset
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
    
public:
    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, EditDefaultsOnly)
    FText Name;

    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, EditDefaultsOnly)
    FText Description;

    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, EditDefaultsOnly, EditFixedSize)
    TArray<UPerkData*> TeachablePerks;

    USurvivorData();

    virtual EDataValidationResult IsDataValid(FDataValidationContext& Context) const override;
};
```

CPP:

```cpp
#include "SurvivorData.h"
#include "Misc/DataValidation.h"

USurvivorData::USurvivorData()
    : TeachablePerks({ nullptr, nullptr, nullptr })
{ }

EDataValidationResult USurvivorData::IsDataValid(FDataValidationContext& Context) const
{
    if (TeachablePerks.Num() != 3)
    {
        Context.AddError(FText::FromString(TEXT("Number of teachable perks can only be 3!")));
        return EDataValidationResult::Invalid;
    }

    return EDataValidationResult::Valid;
}
```

For anyone curious, I'd encourage them to read the official documentation about data validation [here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.3/en-US/data-validation-in-unreal-engine/).

So that wraps it up. `TStaticArray` is great for use as a private field or as a variable in code. Should you need an array for use in the editor however, blueprint or not, you should use `TArray`.

Comment: Glad you solved, and nice catch about uproperties